# Mediawiki tag extension - chained tags do not get processed

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm trying to develop a simple [Tag Extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTag_extensions) for Mediawiki. So far I'm basically outputing the input as it comes. The problem arises when there are chained tags. For instance, for this example:

```
function efSampleParserInit( Parser &$parser ) {
        $parser->setHook( 'sample', 'efSampleRender' );
        return true;
}

function efSampleRender( $input, array $args, Parser $parser, PPFrame $frame ) {
    return "hello ->" .  $input . "<- hello";
}
```

If I write this in an article:

```
This is the text <sample type="1">hello my <sample type="2">brother</sample> John</sample>
```

Only the first `sample` tag gets processed. The other one isn't. I guess I should work with the `$parser` object I receive so I return the parsed input, but I don't know how to do it.

Furthermore, Mediawiki's reference is pretty much non existant, it would be great to have something like a Doxygen reference or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$parser->recursiveTagParse()`, as shown at [Manual:Tag_extensions#How do I render wikitext in my extension?](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTag_extensions#How_do_I_render_wikitext_in_my_extension.3F).

It is kind of a clunky interface, and not very well documented.  The underlying reason why such a seemingly natural thing to do is so tricky to accomplish is that it sort of goes against the original design intent of tag extensions — they were originally conceived as low-level filters that take in raw unparsed text and spit out HTML, completely bypassing normal parsing.  So, for example, if you wanted to include some content written in [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (such as a StackOverflow post) on a wiki page, the idea was that you could install a suitable extension and then write

```
<markdown>
**Look,** here's some Markdown text!
</markdown>
```

on the page, and the MediaWiki parser would leave everything between the <markdown> tags alone and just hand it over to the extension for parsing.

Of course, it turned out that most people who wrote MediaWiki tag extensions didn't really want to replace the parser, but just to apply some tweaks to it.  But the way the tag extension interface was set up, the only way to do that was to call the parser recursively.  I've sometimes thought it would be nice to add a new parser extension type to MediaWiki, something that *looked* like tag extensions but didn't interrupt normal parsing in such a drastic manner.  Alas, my motivation and copious free time hasn't so far been sufficient to actually do something about it.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to correctly parse nested tags of the same type. 

For instance, using this: `return "[ " . $parser -> recursiveTagParse ($input, $frame) . " ]";`

And this input: `<sample>Before <sample> Inside </sample> After </sample>`

The output I get is `[ Before [ Inside ] ] After </sample>`

Comment: Ah, I see.  You may be out of luck: see [MediaWiki bug #1310](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1310).